# How to pass optional arguments to winform commandline

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

So I've written tools in the past where I pass commandline arguments to a winforms c# tool. How can I pass specific arguments which are optional.

```
 Static void test(string name="bill", int age=5, string location = "home")
 {
      Console.writeline (name)
      Console.writeline (age)
 }
```

In simple terms I would like the users to be able to call this function commandline passing age or name or both.
example...

Test name:"JOEY"
Test location:"bed" age:5

Maybe there is a recommendation for the way I write the commandline argument which I parse in a way I can pass optional arguments. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Your question is vague. You want to receive these parameters from the commandline? Or do you want other users to invoke this method?

Comment: why you don't add overloads for your method?

Comment: I will look up overloads. I never heard of them or used them.

Comment: Yeah I want to pass them using commandline to run the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand and as [devdigital](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248164/devdigital) had suggested, you can use the [Command Line Parser Library](https://commandline.codeplex.com/) (available using NuGet). 
I use it in my project in order to start the application in different states. 
First you will define all your accepted parameters (with possibility to set some of them as optional, more info on library docs)

```
public class CommandLineArgs
{
    [Option('t', "type", Required = false, HelpText = "Type of the application [safedispatch, safenet]")]
    public string AppType { get; set; }

    [Option('c', null, HelpText = "Enable the console for this application")]
    public bool Console { get; set; }

    [Option('l', null, HelpText = "Enable the logs for this application")]
    public bool Log { get; set; }

    [Option('h', null, HelpText = "Help for this command line")]
    public bool Help { get; set; }

    [HelpOption]
    public string GetUsage()
    {
        // this without using CommandLine.Text
        //  or using HelpText.AutoBuild
        var usage = HelpText.AutoBuild(this);

        return usage.ToString();
    }
}
```

Next, on you `Program.cs` class, inside the main function you will create a `CommandLineArgs` object and parse the received parameters. Finally you will take the decisions depending on what parameters has been passed to you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var cmdArgs = new CommandLineArgs();
if (args.Length > 0 && CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, cmdArgs))
    {
    // display the help
    if (cmdArgs.Help)
    {
          Utils.WriteLine(cmdArgs.GetUsage());
          Console.ReadKey();
    }

    // display the console
    if (!cmdArgs.Console)
    {
          // hide the console window                   
          setConsoleWindowVisibility(false, Console.Title);
    }

   // verify other console parameters and run your test function
}
else if (args.Length == 0)
{
     // no command line args specified
}

// other lines ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That helps give me enough headway to get something working and do some more research

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to use a command line parsing library such as the [Command Line Parser Library](https://commandline.codeplex.com/) or the [Fluent Command Line Parser](http://fclp.github.io/fluent-command-line-parser/), both available via NuGet.